# Calling function from C# DLL in MC++ code

Tags: c#, managed-c++

i have a c# dll that contains classes for communication with fiscal device. 
The problem is that i have to access the classes from MC++ program.

Can anyone give me few tips or direction on how i may do this. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: add the c# dll to the references of the mc++ project and simple use the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the comment by codeteq you need to add a reference to the c# assembly.

also in your code you need to reference it - this example:

```
//hello.cpp
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;

int main()  {
  Console::WriteLine("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B

this article provides more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310674